# Regular Expression that Includes a Character Only If Another Character Precedes It

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm new to Stack so not sure if I'm asking this right.

I'm trying to form a regular expression to match all characters except 3 specific ones (%,&,and$) but I want to ignore that exception if a backslash () proceeds any of those characters.  For example, if I have the string

```
abcd\$&
```

I would want the regular expression to match

```
abcd\$
```

because a backsplash preceeds the dollar sign, but not match the ^ because no backslash precedes it.

So far I have:

```
^[^%$&]+
```

which matches any string that doesn't have the characters (%, $, or &), but it stops at the backslash rather than include the backslash and the next character.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
^([^%$&\\]|\\.)+$
```

should work.

It also excludes `\` from the charset and then allows `\` followed by any character.

Comment: Hey Mike, this gives me "sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression" in Python.  Any ideas? I picked through your regex, but didn't seem to see anything wrong.

Comment: @Jasper, `re.compile(r'^([^%$&\\]|\\.)+$')` works for me.  Are you using a raw string?

Comment: My bad, I forgot the r.  Only thing is, when I run:  
m = re.search(r'^([^%$&\\]|\\.)+', 'abc\$')
and then m.group(0), it returns 'abc\\$' instead of 'abc\$'

Comment: @JasperJohansen That shouldn't even work. You need to double escape the backslash `m = re.search(r'^([^%$&\\]|\\.)+', 'abc\$')`

Comment: @JasperJohansen: When you post a comment with source code in it, be sure to enclose the code in backticks.  Otherwise, some of the characters can get dropped because the site interprets them as markup.  This is especially true for regexes and backslashes.